# How to create a dropdown from the given table

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I have the following table: (only a snippet is given of many rows)

```
|name_id | house  |  school | duration  |
|1       |red     | abc     |  20       |
|2       |yello   | dps     |  30       |
|3       |blue    | gdf     |  40       |
|4       |pink    | abc     |  20       |
|5       |red     | dps     |  10       |
|6       |blue    | gdf     |   5       |
```

And I want to apply a vizualization such that: two dropdown menus for house and school are created.

To do my visual I am using the following:

1. I have the data as a pandas dataframe.
2. I use altair code as follows:

```js
import altair as alt

input_dropdown1 = alt.binding_select(options=['abc','dps','gdf'])
input_dropdown2 = alt.binding_select(options=['red','yello','blue','pink'])
selection1 = alt.selection_single(fields=['house'], bind=input_dropdown1, name='belonging ')
selection2 = alt.selection_single(fields=['school'], bind=input_dropdown2, name='origin ')

 
alt.Chart(df1).mark_point().encode(
    x='name_id:Q',
    y='duration:Q',
    color='house'
).add_selection(
    selection1,
    selection2
)
```

However, The code is not being rendered properly.

And when I tried to have just one dropdown menu - no filtering happens.

I am using altair the first time.

The idea precisely here is to have a plot of name_id vs duration and using filters to see the plot more closely for each house and school.

I would be happy if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```js
import altair as alt

input_dropdown1 = alt.binding_select(options=['abc','dps','gdf'])
input_dropdown2 = alt.binding_select(options=['red','yello','blue','pink'])
selection1 = alt.selection_single(fields=['house'], bind=input_dropdown1, name='belonging ')
selection2 = alt.selection_single(fields=['school'], bind=input_dropdown2, name='origin ')

 
alt.Chart(df1).mark_point().encode(
    x='name_id:Q',
    y='duration:Q',
    color='house',
    ##### added the opacity ,here
    opacity=alt.condition(
         selection1 & selection2,
         alt.value(1),
         alt.value(0.1)
)).add_selection(
    selection1,
    selection2
)
```